# custom timestamp extractor in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use kafka streams to process some data from a kafka topic. The data comes from kafka topic that was written to by kafka 0.11.0 something which doesn't have the embedded timestamp. After some reading on the internet, I came to understand that I can solve this problem by extending `TimestampExtractor` class in a custom class and passing it in the `StreamsConfig`.

I did so like this --

```
class MyEventTimestampExtractor extends TimestampExtractor {
  override def extract(record: ConsumerRecord[AnyRef, AnyRef], prev: Long) = {
    record.value() match {
        case w: String => 1000L
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Called for $record")
    }
  }
}
```

I based it off of [this code on github](https://github.com/softwaremill/its-pres/blob/master/kafka/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/its/KafkaHotspotDetector.scala#L263-L277)

But, I get this error when I do an `sbt run`

```
[error] /home/someuser/app/blahblah/src/main/scala/main.scala:34: class MyEventTimestampExtractor needs to be abstract, since method extract in trait TimestampExtractor of type (x$1: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[Object,Object], x$2: Long)Long is not defined
[error] (Note that Long does not match Long)
[error] class MyEventTimestampExtractor extends TimestampExtractor {
[error]       ^
[error] /home/someuser/app/blahblah/src/main/scala/main.scala:35: method extract overrides nothing.
[error] Note: the super classes of class MyEventTimestampExtractor contain the following, non final members named extract:
[error] def extract(x$1: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[Object,Object],x$2: Long): Long
[error]   override def extract(record: ConsumerRecord[AnyRef, AnyRef], prev: Long): Long = {
[error]                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

My build.sbt file is this --

```
name := "kafka streams experiment"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % "1.0.0"
)
```

I don't really understand the error. Specifically the part around `Note that Long does not match Long`. What could I be doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it without the `override` keyword?

Comment: I didn't provide all the context in the the question :(
I imported scala long that was coming in the way of java long and causing the compilation to fail :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need java.Long since this API is defined in Java whereas you are using Scala Long

Answer (score 0):

Try with (watch the type of the `prev` function argument:

```
  override def extract(record: ConsumerRecord[AnyRef, AnyRef], prev: java.lang.Long) = {
```